# XMLWorkerHelper.ParseXHtml removes existing text on the pdf if it has multiple pages to write on

Tags: itext

By using XMLWorkerHelper.ParseXHtml, I am trying to add some HTML text to the existing pdf file. This pdf file already has some blank spaces to accommodate new HTML text. What happens is for the first page that I am editing, everything works correctly (no text is lost), but for subsequent pages, existing text is completely replaced by the text from the HTML file. Here's the code excerpts:

```
string pdfFilename = @"D:\Somepdf.pdf";
    string htmlFilePath = @"D:\someHtml.html";

    using (var reader = new PdfReader(pdfFilename))
    {
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(@"D:\Newpdf.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            var document = new Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(2));
            var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fileStream);               
            document.Open();

            string htmlText = File.ReadAllText(htmlFilePath);

            TextReader tr = new StringReader(htmlText);

            XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, document, tr); //

        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: **A** You forgot to close the document. **B** The only information you seem to transfer from "D:\Somepdf.pdf" to "D:\Newpdf.pdf" is the document page size. Thus, it is hard to believe that any old text made it into the new document.

Comment: Thanks mkl for pointing it out. I will make necessary adjustments and check the output.